# Transfer data from a PLC on remote server into MQTT

Tags: python, beginner, ssh

Newbie here. I want to write a code that can open an SSH Tunnel for a remote server, then read out the data from a PLC and transfers it in JSON format via MQTT. This is my code, but I don't think this is a the clearest and most effective version of it. I want to host it in Azure Function and trigger it once a day with Azure Logic App. How should I improve my code?

```
# This is the main script file of the PLC Reader of MET3R project.
# It is used to read the data from the PLC and send it to the server.
# Author: name
# License: MIT


# Imported libraries
import time
import json
import subprocess

# Imported third party libraries
import BAC0
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

# Import secrets
from secrets.secrets import broker_address, plc_address, target_mqtt_server
from secrets.secrets import ssh_user, ssh_password, ssh_privatekey, ssh_local_port, ssh_port


# Functions

def create_ssh_tunnel():
    print('Creating SSH Tunnel at ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    try:
        tunnel = subprocess.Popen(
            ['ssh', '-i', ssh_privatekey, '-N', '-L', f'{ssh_local_port}:{plc_address}:{ssh_local_port}',
             f'{ssh_user}@{broker_address}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if tunnel.returncode is not None and tunnel.returncode != 0:
            print(f"Failed to create SSH tunnel: {tunnel.stderr.read().decode()}")
        else:
            print("SSH tunnel created successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating SSH tunnel: {e}")
    time.sleep(5)


def check_broker_connection():
    # Check connection to the MQTT Broker
    print('Checking connection to the MQTT Broker...')
    try:
        # Create a new MQTT client
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.tls_set()
        client.username_pw_set(ssh_user, ssh_password)
        client.connect(broker_address, int(ssh_port), bind_address='127.0.0.1', bind_port=int(ssh_local_port))
        # Disconnect from the MQTT Broker
        client.disconnect()
        # Return True if the connection was successful
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # Return False if the connection was not successful
        print('The exception was: ' + str(e))
        return False


def check_plc_connection():
    # Check connection to the PLC
    try:
        # Create a new BAC0 object
        bacnet = BAC0.lite()
        # Read the value of the object
        bacnet.read(plc_address, 'analogValue', 1)
        # Return True if the connection was successful
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # Return False if the connection was not successful
        print('The exception was: ' + str(e))
        return False


def check_target_mqtt_server_connection():
    # Check connection to the target MQTT server
    print('Checking connection to the target MQTT server...')
    try:
        # Create a new MQTT client
        client = mqtt.Client()
        # Connect to the target MQTT server
        client.connect(target_mqtt_server)
        # Disconnect from the target MQTT server
        client.disconnect()
        # Return True if the connection was successful
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # Return False if the connection was not successful
        print('The exception was: ' + str(e))
        return False


def connection_checker():
    # Check the connections
    print('Checking connections...')
    # Check the connection to the MQTT Broker
    if check_broker_connection():
        # Check the connection to the PLC
        print('Connection to the MQTT Broker was successful.')
    else:
        print('Connection to the MQTT Broker was not successful.')
    if check_plc_connection():
        # Check the connection to the target MQTT server
        print('Connection to the PLC was successful.')
    else:
        print('Connection to the PLC was not successful.')

    if check_target_mqtt_server_connection():
        # Return True if all the connections were successful
        print('Connection to the target MQTT server was successful.')
    else:
        print('Connection to the target MQTT server was not successful.')


def read_plc_to_json():
    # Read the PLC
    print('Reading the PLC...')
    # Create a new BAC0 object
    bacnet = BAC0.lite()
    # Read the value of the object
    value = bacnet.read(plc_address, 'analogValue', 1)

    # Convert the value to a JSON object
    json_data = json.dumps({'data': value})

    # Return the JSON data
    return json_data


# Main function
def main():
    print('Starting PLC Reader script at ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    # Create the SSH tunnel
    create_ssh_tunnel()

    # Check the connections
    if connection_checker():
        print('All connections are successful.')
        json_data = read_plc_to_json()
        print('Data read from the PLC: ' + str(json_data))

        # Publish the data to the MQTT Broker
        publish.single('targetServer/plc', json_data, hostname=target_mqtt_server, port=broker_port)


# Run the main script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried my best to collect the libraries needed and create a valid solution for my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code to that it is actually valid Python.

Comment: @RichardNeumann did it and thank you, I didn't notice

Comment: You might want to delete the original question on stack overflow. To generally improve your questions in the future please read our [help section on asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) starting with [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to gather some thoughts around your problem statement. When you say you want this to run as daily once Azure function - it _cannot_ be run as it is. There should be different python program that reads from PLC card and sends message to, ideally Azure Event Hub [not vanilla mqtt server], then you could process this event hub messages - either immediately via `trigger` functions, or once a day.